# Escape '(ticks) in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP where I print some string by use of c:out. But I need to escape all **'** (ticks) by an back slash.

Example: jsp

```
<span onclick=
    "document.getElementById('input').value+='<c:outvalue="${tag.title}" />'">
 <c:out value="${tag.title}" />
</span>
```

Prints for tag.title = test‘s

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('input').value+='test's'">
 'test's
</span>
```

But I need:

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('input').value+='test\'s'">
 'test's
</span>
```

Is there any **easy** way to do this in jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang), import [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) and use one of its methods (I think that would be [escapeJavascript](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) in your case)

Comment: You can also map this method as a JSP function, so that you can call it in the EL such as `${z:escapeJavascript(theJs)}`.

Answer (score 1):

In your getTitle() method you can return yourString.replaceAll("**'**","");

edit:

try

```
${fn:replace(yourString, "'", "")}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 ${fn:replace(text, "'", "")}
```

or add some jsp in and use string.replace()

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a sign that a bit of refactoring would be advised.

Specifically stop outputting html via jstl tags and instead use `if` or `when`; or do a bigger refactoring.

I would probably use jQuery and assign click functions based on class (which could be taken from server side paramters)

Comment: How would `if` or `when` help? - I really do not understand your answer?